# What does a base Windows 7 root file system look like?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, windows-installation

What directories and files should I see in the root (C:) of a fresh Windows 7 Professional 64-bit installation (including hidden files and directories)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excluding the later additions I can reliably identify, here are the Directories I see:

```
$Recycle.Bin
Boot
Config.Msi [Possibly created by Office]
Documents and Settings [Junction point to Users directory below, as "dir /al" will show]
MSOCache [Possibly created by Office]
PerfLogs
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
ProgramData
Recovery
System Volume Information
Users
Windows
```

And the files:

```
BOOTSECT.BAK [Possibly created later and missing from a fresh install/at first boot]
bootmgr
hiberfil.sys [Possibly missing if hibernation is not enabled]
pagefile.sys
```

Comment: This includes all hidden files correct?

Comment: Yes it does, all hidden and system files/dirs.

Comment: Note that the "Documents and Settings" entry is a junction pointing to c:\users, and not a directory.

Comment: @kreemoweet: Correct. `dir /al` displays `<JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]`